# IIS 7.5 redirect catch-all exclude a file

Tags: iis

I have a directory with 100+ sub folders and files.

/Whatever/...

I want to redirect any request to the /Whatever/* folder to /Whatever/temp.html

The problem i'm having is that after I setup the redirect I get an endless redirect loop because /whatever/temp.html matched /Whatever/* so how can I exclude a file from a redirect?

IIS 7.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to do it using the IIS redirect feature. Either create a different folder to redirect them to or exclude the target folder by redirect each individual folder using wildcards. You might want to try the url rewrite module http://www.iis.net/download/URLRewrite

Comment: I ended up going with url rewrite module. It has much more flexibility so I can send query strings along with it too.

Answer (score 1):

You can setup different pages to be "default documents".  Look into adding temp.html to the list of default documents.

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/203/default-documents/

Comment: I didn't want to setup additional pages such as with using the 404 approach.

Comment: Understood.  Actually, I was referring to making temp.html an alternative to index.html, for example.  Unfortunately I missed that you had to do this for a bunch of subfolders.